# Why wouldn't this css3 work in webkit for sliding text from right to left?

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-animations

I'm trying to get text to slide from left to right using webkit transforms. I realize I could use `<marquee>` to do this (even though it's going away) but I need better control of the animation using keyframes. The CSS below doesn't seem to move the text in any direction and I can't imagine why.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="container">
            <header>
            <h1>Some header test sliding</h1>
            </header>
          </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
#container header h1{
-webkit-animation-name: slider; 
-webkit-animation-duration: 26s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@webkit-keyframes slider{
    0%{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
    70%{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(175px);
    }
    75%{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(85px);
    }
    80%{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
    }
    85%{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(35px);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your selectors are correct?

Comment: just a note I put -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; just to test, I realize <marquee> would be just as good but I'm looking for something much better presentationally and keyframes are awesome for it.

Comment: You should edit your original question instead of posting this as a comment.

Comment: Also, obviously unpremitted tags are stripped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for declaring keyframes is **@-webkit-keyframes** not **@webkit-kayframes**. Removing the hyphen kills it:

Your code, now with hyphens!: http://jsfiddle.net/eL2UC/

Comment: Bah!! Always something so derp that's the answer. Thanks!!